# JS: conditional classes in template literal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use conditional classes in template literals but the code won't compile.  Is something like this not possible?

```
let isNewType = true;
  
const html = `
    <div
      class="${isNewType} ?  'foo' : 'newFoo'"
    </dov>
  `;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ternary needs to be inside of the `${}`

```js
let isNewType = true;
  
const html = `
    <div
      class="${isNewType ?  'foo' : 'newFoo'}"
    </div>
  `;
  
  console.log(html)
```